# Powershell, mongosh devops Pipeline. runs but never updates

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongo-shell

Cant get the pipeline to work so brought it local
This connects to Azure CosmosDB MongoDB with creds in connection string
Opens new powershell window loads mongosh but crashes without error. No update to data in cosmosdb (mongodb instance)

```
# Set the path to your mongosh executable
$mongoShellPath = 'D:\MongoDB\Tools\mongosh.exe'

# Set your connection string
$connectionString = 'mongodb://TrustmeItWorks'

# Set the path to your JavaScript file
$mongoScriptPath = 'D:\MongoDB\Mikes.js'

# Construct the command
$evalArgument = "load(`"$mongoScriptPath`")"
$command = "& '$mongoShellPath' '$connectionString' --eval '$evalArgument'"

# Execute the command
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command $command" -Wait
```

Extra..
This will launch in the same powershell window and wait for the command
Seems to need --eval in powershell to pass the "load("D:/MongoDB/Mikes.js")" method

```
"load("D:/MongoDB/Mikes.js")" the load method only works with the forward slashes not back in mongosh

# Set the path to your mongosh executable
$mongoShellPath = 'D:\MongoDB\Tools\mongosh.exe'

# Set your connection string
$connectionString = 'mongodb://TrustmeThisWorks'

# Construct the command
$command = "& '$mongoShellPath' '$connectionString'"

# Execute the command
Invoke-Expression $command
```

.js has this

```
var collection = 'MikesContext';

use('UpDogData');
db[collection].drop();
db.createCollection(collection);
db[collection].createIndex({ MikesId: 1 });

db[collection].insert({
    "_id": "98765309",
    "_t": "MikesContext",
    "MikesId": 65309,
    "MikesName": "Mike",
    "UWGuideLink": "https://mikedopp.com/happy.pdf",
    "KnowledgeBaseLink": ""
});
```

Stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"load("D:/MongoDB/Mikes.js")"` does not work.

But you can use one of these:

- `"load('D:/MongoDB/Mikes.js')"`
- `` "load(`D:/MongoDB/Mikes.js`)" ``
- `"load(\"D:/MongoDB/Mikes.js\")"`
- Backslashes can be uses when you escape them like `D:\\MongoDB\\Mikes.js`

However, you don't need neither `--eval` nor `load(...)`. Simply use

```
'$mongoShellPath' '$connectionString' 'D:\MongoDB\Mikes.js'
```

`db[collection]` does not work either. Try `db.getCollection(collection)`

Missing collections are created automatically, thus you can skip `db.createCollection(collection)`